# Error BLOC state [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError

Tags: http, flutter, dart, bloc

first of all, i got an error look like this

```
I/flutter ( 3245): BLOC Start
I/flutter ( 3245): BLOC Start

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building BlocBuilder<StationBloc, StationState>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<StationBloc, StationState>#24ede):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BlocBuilder<StationBloc, StationState> file:///C:/Users/junia/FlutterApp/airportstation/airport_station/lib/view/home_screen.dart:42:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _HomeScreenState.buildStationList (package:airport_station/view/home_screen.dart:79:30)
#2      _HomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:airport_station/view/home_screen.dart:51:24)
#3      BlocBuilder.build (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:90:57)
#4      _BlocBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:162:48)
```

Then, i went to stackoverflow and found a litte solution

```
Widget buildStationList(List<AllFlight> allFlight) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: allFlight.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: InkWell(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(allFlight[index].airportName + ' - ' + allFlight[index].countryName),
                subtitle: Text(allFlight[index].label),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
```

the problem is on `itemCount: allFlight.length,` and i change it into `itemCount: allFlight?.length ?? 0,`

after i run it again. there's still an error

```
I/flutter ( 3245): BLOC Start
I/flutter ( 3245): BLOC Start
E/flutter ( 3245): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError
E/flutter ( 3245): #0      StationLoadedState.props (package:airport_station/bloc/station_state.dart:23:29)
E/flutter ( 3245): #1      Equatable.== (package:equatable/src/equatable.dart:50:18)
E/flutter ( 3245): #2      Bloc._bindEventsToStates.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:261:32)
E/flutter ( 3245): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 3245): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 3245): #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter ( 3245): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #8      _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendData (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:385:25)
E/flutter ( 3245): #9      _BroadcastStreamController._add (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:293:5)
E/flutter ( 3245): #10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 3245): #11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 3245): #12     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter ( 3245): #14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #15     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)
E/flutter ( 3245): #16     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:224:10)
E/flutter ( 3245): #17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter ( 3245): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 3245): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 3245): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter ( 3245): #22     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:611:14)
E/flutter ( 3245): #23     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11)
E/flutter ( 3245): #24     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter ( 3245): #26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 3245): #27     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #28     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 3245): #29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 3245): #30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 3245): #31     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 3245): #32     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 3245): #33     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 3245): #34     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter ( 3245):
```

my bloc_state.dart look like this

```
...

class StationLoadedState extends StationState {
  final List<AllFlight> allFlight;

  StationLoadedState({ @required this.allFlight });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}

...
```

and BlocBuilder

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  StationBloc stationBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stationBloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
    stationBloc.add(FetchStationEvent());
  }

...

body: Container(
        child: BlocListener<StationBloc, StationState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is StationErrorState) {
              print(state.message);
            }
          },
          child: BlocBuilder<StationBloc, StationState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              print('BLOC Start');
              if (state is StationInitialState) {
                return buildLoading();
              } else if (state is StationLoadingState) {
                return buildLoading();
              } else if (state is StationLoadedState) {
                return buildStationList(state.allFlight);
              } else if (state is StationErrorState) {
                return buildError(state.message);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
...
```

json response returned successfully when i try print it on http response. did someone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlocState has a "props" getter which should return an array of variables to compare states between each other. When you yield same state 2 times in a row, it will compare them using those props and if it's the same state as current - bloc will not yield it again (this is the default way it works when you're using Equatable).

In your code above you have this:

```dart
class StationLoadedState extends StationState {
  final List<AllFlight> allFlight;

  StationLoadedState({ @required this.allFlight });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

It throws UnimplementedError when props are called. Change it to an array with your state's params.

```dart
class StationLoadedState extends StationState {
  final List<AllFlight> allFlight;

  StationLoadedState({ @required this.allFlight });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [allFlight];
}
```

Comment: I already try those changes but it return nothing. My screen's empty and there's no error in my logcat

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that state has a parameter. Corrected the code. Do you ever call a code that actually yields StationLoadedState (there's no BLoC example in your post)? Also be sure to close the page that is using this BLoC and open it again or restart your application for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks @Thepeanut , the code work properly, didn't expect that i just need put the 'allFlight' into the param. Thank's for helping me, btw i already call the yield inside the bloc file.